# Do you "chew" yogurt? What is the correct verb?

Tags: verbs, food

Someone told me (half) jokingly that I should be able to eat my yogurt (plain Greek yogurt) quickly since I don't have to chew it.  We then started wondering if chewing is the correct verb for when yogurt is in your mouth.  I'm talking specifically about when the yogurt is in your mouth before you swallow it, when you break it up with your tongue but not necessarily with your teeth (or at least I think that's what I do!).  **What is this called?**

Just a fun question, couldn't find anything online about the proper term (if there is one), and I have seen people on here find interesting terms for things like this!

Update1:  Edited the question to be more specific about what I was really asking (sorry!).

Comment: For anything you swallow, if you use a utensil, you are _eating_ it. If you simply drain the contents of a container into your mouth, you are _drinking_ it. That's enough.

Comment: Fair enough.  Was merely curious if there was an equivalent word for chewing with yogurt (or similar foods).  We just eat it I guess.

Comment: If it contains pieces of something, fruit for example, you can chew those.

Comment: Sometimes having a specific word for an activity is pointless.  Granted, English probably has a few such pointless words, but there's no real reason to expect one in this case.

Comment: @Hot Licks  I understand.  Was just for fun/curiousity.  I've been impressed by the words people have found for other questions on this site and thought I'd give this one a try.

Comment: One verb for ingesting liquids, including viscous and partly solid ones like yogurt, is *slurp*.

Comment: @Drew Should make that an answer

Comment: @DCShannon: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can chew yogurt and it is recommended but it is not a usual verb to use with yogurt and it would sound strange to use in everyday speech. Obviously the most common verb is ***eat***.

> Foods that are already mostly liquid, such as jello or yogurt, should be chewed the same as solid foods to allow the saliva to break them down before entering the stomach.
>
> [[How to chew food properly/Wikihow]](http://www.wikihow.com/Chew-Food-Properly)

Chewing food without teeth is called ***gumming***.

> Chew with toothless gums: *some grandmother gumming a meal* [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gum#gum)

---

Also, *chewing* is used sometimes when toothless babies eat food with a chewing-like motion.

Comment: I'll go with that. Saliva might be *produced* in the mouth, but I think it has a lot of work to do further down the digestive tract. I imagine moving the lower jaw and tongue are both helpful to the process even when the actual *teeth* take no real part.

Comment: Do you 'chew' your soup as well?

Comment: @WS2: No. Do you?

Comment: @ermanen I apologise. It was not you but your quoted source that was recommending the chewing of yoghurt. I wonder if they chew their soup?

Comment: @WS2: Soup is more liquidy so it doesn't apply. I think it depends on the viscosity of the food. But chewing also has several mechanisms that can include pressing the food with your tongue against the palate.

Comment: The veggies were added too soon if you don't have to chew your soup.

Answer (score 3):

I have never had yoghurt which is of a sufficiently tough-enough consistency to require ***chewing***.

According to my dictionary the verb ***chew*** does involve use of the teeth, and biting and/or gnawing.

Comment: I thought the "h" in "yogurt" was a typo, but then I checked it before making any comment.

Comment: I'll go with that. You may use your tongue to mix it with saliva and play with it, but it certainly isn't chewing.

Comment: Now that the question has been updated this is only half an answer. Need to provide an alternate verb.

Answer (score 2):

One verb for ingesting liquids, including viscous and partly solid ones like yogurt, is *slurp*.

Answer (score 1):

The verb for ingesting yoghurt in your mouth is simply *eating*.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with **gobbled** [down] or ate yogurt.

> eat hastily without proper chewing